# How to setInterval countdown for correct element index in the array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

The problem I have is inside my `componentDidUpdate()` every time component updates the `setInterval` will countdown for every patient that has value for `patient.locationInfo` and `patient.status` each time. I need to only countdown for correct patient index in the array that has values in `patient.locationInfo` and `patient.status` and they have the value set when the user clicks on `Patient location column` Buttons and `Patient Obs detail column` has text/string in it.

```
componentDidUpdate() {

 this.state.patientInfo.forEach((patient, i) => {

           let seconds = 0;
           if (patient.locationInfo.length !== 0 && patient.status.length !== 0) {
               const checkoutMinPassed = setInterval(() => {
                   seconds++;

                   if (seconds === 5) {
                       clearInterval(checkoutMinPassed);
                       alert(patient.name + ' reached a min');
                   }
               }, 1000);
           }
       });


   }
```

```
PatientInfo Array

patientInfo = [
           { room: "1", name: 'John Nero', locationInfo: '', status: ''},
           { room: "2", name: 'Shawn Mic',  locationInfo: '', status: ''},
           { room: "3", name: 'Gereth Ma',  locationInfo: '', status: ''},
           { room: "4", name: 'Elminster',  locationInfo: '', status: ''},
           { room: "5", name: 'Rincewind',  locationInfo: '', status: ''},
```

Table UI 
say if the 1st, 2nd, 3rd have already got values locationInfo and status. when the user input for the 4th patient the setInterval will countdown for every patient. I only need the countdown for 4th patient because the top 3 already have values.

Comment: Have you considered to use ONE global timer? In that timer you can fetch all elements that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable for timer id.

```
    let checkoutMinPassed; 
    // at the top and outside of your component.

    // then inside your component,
              checkoutMinPassed = setTimeout(()=> { 
                   if (seconds === 5) {
                   clearInterval(checkoutMinPassed);;
                   }
                       }, 1000)
```